# Limit of an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What do you think of the following statement:

> Let $f$ be an increasing and strictly concave function with $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$. Then $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0.$$

Comment: I think it's a pretty short statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about $f(x)=x-\exp(-x)$ ?